# How to change fillColor of a specific area using react-img-mapper library onClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, colors

I want to specifically change an area's fillColor with an onClick function of a button. But when I do area.fillColor = 'colorThatIWant' it doesn't change or update.

I have tried changing the fillColor property on the map itself but that is not what I wanted.